# String Sorting in Scheme

Tags: sorting, scheme

I'm new to scheme. 
I'm wondering how to sort strings in scheme.
Now I become to think that using [string=?][string?] will help me to compare contents of the list.
However, I'm still struggling with sort it out, literally.
Does anyone help me to implement this?

Comment: http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-132/srfi-132.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scheme/3191/implementation-of-different-sortings-algorithms#t=201612280745573146071

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
But I would like to sort strings, not numbers. Apparently your links implement sorting exclusively for numbers...

Comment: Simply grab any sorting algorithm and change the comparison to use `string<?`

Answer (score 0):

Most Scheme implementations have a builtin `sort` that can sort lists:

```
> (sort '("How" "to" "sort" "strings" "in" "Scheme") string<?)
'("How" "Scheme" "in" "sort" "strings" "to")
```

If your implementation complain that `sort` is an unbound identifier, then lookup `sort` in the documentation to see how to include it.

Note that the predicate `string<?` is a function that compares two strings.
Using `<` instead you can sort lists of numbers.